# Picking up JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a calendar. Each of its cells (= days) contains

```
    <span class="spanEvent"></span>
    <span class="spanDate"></span>
    <span class="spanParticipants"></span>
    <span class="spanDescription"></span>
```

So, I need my earlier stored data (localStorage.setItem) to appear within those < spans >.

My code (see below) seems not to work. So, how do I do it?

I created a JSON object and made it an array. Each value of the array contains data for a certain day in the calendar. 
"thisCell" is my target cell which I am clicking to retrieve the stored data.

```
    var organizer = [
        //February 9, 2015
        {thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("event")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanDate")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("date")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanParticipants")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("participants")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanDescription")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("description")')
        },

        //July 22, 2016
        {thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("event")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanDate")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("date")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanParticipants")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("participants")'),
         thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanDescription")[0].value: JSON.parse('localStorage.getItem("description")')
        }
      ];
```

Comment: Couple things, I'd try getting JSON values by var eventData = localStorage.getItem("event");  JSON.parse(eventData); Also I'm not 100% sure if thisCell.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent")[0].value works as intended inside of an object declaration;

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a misunderstanding on how to access and modify dom element's content.

Your code will do nothing, because you are just creating an object, not actually accessing a dom's element properties, also, `<span>` elements don't use the `value` property to access it's content, they use, as most `HTMLElements` do, the innerHTML property.

Also, the `JSON.parse(string)` method will convert a string into a `JavaScript Object{}` which, in your case, I believe it's not necessary, given that you are trying to assign that value to a `<span>`, it should be a string, right?

So, with that in mind, I've created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnjek58L/) illustrating what I think you want to do.

### HTML

```
<div class="cell"> 
 <span class="spanEvent"></span>
 <span class="spanDate"></span>
 <span class="spanParticipants"></span>
 <span class="spanDescription"></span>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
localStorage.setItem("event", "someEv");
localStorage.setItem("date", "someDate");
localStorage.setItem("participants", "someParticipants");
localStorage.setItem("desc", "someDesc");

cell = document.querySelector(".cell");
spanEv = cell.querySelector(".spanEvent");
spanDate = cell.querySelector(".spanDate");
spanPart = cell.querySelector(".spanParticipants");
spanDesc = cell.querySelector(".spanDescription");

spanEv.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("event");
spanDate.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("date");
spanPart.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("participants");
spanDesc.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("desc");
```

**Note:** I've used the `querySelector()` method to get the cell and it's elements, but feel free to use any dom selection technique you prefer (`getElementsByClassName()` is by far faster).

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's a bit clear now, thanks. But I think I need to use JSON, because when I use my code (it is based on the principle you mentioned above) I can retrieve the stored data only on a current page. If I, let's say, "turn" my calendar's page from February 2015 to March 2015 and then go back to February 2015, there's no more stored data. It is being erased (from visible < span > area) every time I leave the current page, though it's still in localStorage as Chrome Developer Tools show.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your problem though I don't think JSON.parse() will fix it, but that should be for you to manage I believe! Good luck :)